# Creating SockJS server with Java

Tags: java, sockjs, vert.x

I'm very new with Vert.x so excuse my newbness.

I was able to create a very simply SockJS server with Vert.x however I can't figure out how to register events/callbacks/handlers when connections are open or closed.

With JSR-356, it's drop dead simple to handle open/close connection events:

```
@OnOpen 
public void onOpen(Session userSession) {    
   // Do whatever you need 
}

@OnClose
public void onClose(Session userSession) {    
   // Do whatever you need
}
```

Using the SockJS support in Spring Framework 4.0 M1+, it's almost the same as JSR-356:

```
public class MySockJsServer extends TextWebSocketHandlerAdapter {   
   @Override    
   public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
      // Do whatever you need
   }

   @Override    
   public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
      // Do whatever you need    
   } 
}
```

For some reason I couldn't figure out how to do something so conceptually simple in Vert.x. I though Vert.x was simple ?!!

If anyone can point me in the right direction, please help.

I played around with EventBus and EventBus hooks but it didn't work. Perhaps that's the wrong approach anyhow.

I'm using Vert.x version 2.0.1

TIA

Comment: This is the answer:

sockJSServer = sockJSServer.installApp(new JsonObject().putString("prefix", "/test"), new Handler<SockJSSocket>() {
 public void handle(final SockJSSocket sock) {
  System.out.println("New session detected !");            

  // Session end handler
  sock.endHandler(new Handler<Void>() {
     @Override
     public void handle(Void arg) {
     System.out.println("In endHandler");
     }
  });
 }
});

httpServer.listen(8080);

Answer (score 5):

This is the answer:

```
  HttpServer httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer();

  // Create HTTP server
  httpServer = httpServer.requestHandler(new Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {
     @Override
     public void handle(HttpServerRequest req) {
        req.response().sendFile("web/" + req.path());
     }
  });

  // Create SockJS Server
  SockJSServer sockJSServer = vertx.createSockJSServer(httpServer);

  sockJSServer = sockJSServer.installApp(new JsonObject().putString("prefix", "/test"), new Handler<SockJSSocket>() {

     public void handle(final SockJSSocket sock) {
        System.out.println("New session detected!");

        // Message handler
        sock.dataHandler(new Handler<Buffer>() {
           public void handle(Buffer buffer) {
              System.out.println("In dataHandler");
           }
        });

        // Session end handler
        sock.endHandler(new Handler<Void>() {
           @Override
           public void handle(Void arg) {
              System.out.println("In endHandler");
           }
        });
     }
  });

  httpServer.listen(8080);
```